# Shadows flickering in Eevee animation

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I'm trying to render a 10 second, 30 FPS character turntable in Eevee:
[image: Still frame of the turntable animation with highlighted problematic area]

The scene has two lights - a spotlight and a sun with disabled shadow casting, at a nearly 90 degree angle from each other. The materials are highly specular and metallic and use ambient occlusion to achieve a more comic book-like look. Screen space reflections are disabled to preserve the high light reflectivity without having differently coloured areas reflecting each other.

Still image renders look perfectly fine but during the animation, you can clearly see the shadows cast by the strands of hair on the character's forehead flickering, as if they were much stronger in every other frame. This doesn't seem to happen with any other part of the model, only the hair. I've marked the affected area on the provided image.

I've tried a number of solutions to similar problems I've found online: changing the shadow settings (soft shadows are off), light volumetrics properties, camera clipping distance, simply increasing the render samples. None of it has had any effect whatsoever. I've tried removing my ambient occlusion nodes from the hair and skin materials and this did have an effect, but it seemed to only mask the issue by making the shadows more faint and it didn't eliminate the flickering itself.

My best guess would be that the issue comes either from the materials or the geometry - I've had neither the time nor the need to retopologise the model, so some of the geometry might be questionable (especially due to lots of wasted vertices). I'm not convinced that's related to my problem, though.

The obvious solution would be to switch to Cycles (which does not have this issue at all) but since there are a lot of dark areas on the model, noise becomes a major concern and I've found the render times unacceptable for 300 frames, even with OptiX denoising.

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: Sure, here's one with the most recent settings I've used. I also added a part of the animation from one of the earlier attempts. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Pk6mgvMdzCXogmps6fqLbX_Pjd2B7Cnd?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this is possibly because the hair is coming close to the shadow buffer pixel size.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I think you may be right, but I don't really know what to do about it. I've tried baking indirect lighting and it seems to help a little bit, but not that much. I already had all the shadow options set to be as accurate as I could make them, so I don't know what else could work. The only idea I have is scaling the model up, but I can't imagine that would actually work.

Comment: @ImaginosDelRio Maybe just for an experiment try moving the camera closer to the hair?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I have tried that before, actually. I didn't really see any improvement, the flickering was still clearly visible. I've also tried scaling the model up (5 times) - no real effect either, except for decreased AO due to the materials not being made for that scale.